# How do I compile multiple files with sweet.js?

Tags: javascript, macros, sweet.js

How do I compile multiple files using the sweet.js binary?

So that something like this: `sjs -o out *.js`...

...generates separate compiled files in the `out` directory:

```
out/one.js
out/two.js
out/three.js
```

This is for an npm module that `require()`'s several internal files.

**Edit:** I am motivated to do this in a single call to `sjs` because I am importing a sweetjs module with `-m lambda-chop/macros` which is slow. Running separate `sjs -m lambda-chop/macros` commands for every source file makes for an unnecessarily slow build process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the power of your shell. Something like:

```
find *.js -type f -print | xargs  -L 1 -I % sjs -o out/% %
```

**Edit:**

Or a much better solution when speed is a concern is a proper build tool that can keep things in memory:

- [broccoli-sweet](https://github.com/sindresorhus/broccoli-sweetjs)
- [grunt-sweet](https://github.com/natefaubion/grunt-sweet.js)
- [gulp-sweet](https://github.com/jlongster/gulp-sweetjs)

Comment: This appears to simply compile each file in sequence, overwriting a file `out` each time, instead of outputting separate files into a directory `out`.

Comment: My bad, just edited my answer to be a bit more right :)

Comment: Thanks! If you were using external modules (like lambda-chop) and had dozens of source files to compile, wouldn't this be extremely slow? Is this what developers are using for large-scale projects?

Comment: Maybe an incremental build system like [Broccoli](http://broccolijs.com/) would work well with sweetjs for this reason...?

Comment: Ah yes! If you need speed definitely use grunt or broccoli. Looks like there's already a broccoli plugin for sweet: https://github.com/sindresorhus/broccoli-sweetjs